# Avoiding multiple requests to Google geocode using only frontend scripting

Tags: javascript, google-maps, frontend

We have many addresses and we want to showing it on a map using Google Maps API (without setting up server/proxy for caching).

To avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error, I added timeout for requests but it's too slow on rendering.

Check this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/Funfun/6450394 ( and source https://gist.github.com/Funfun/6450394 )

Wondering how to fix that problem using only frontend side of client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache some data on client side using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

To ensure cross-browser compatibility and make it easier to serialize/de-serialize objects you can also use [`store.js`](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) library.

Comment: Good one about caching, forgot about it.
Only one thing, second and later requests will be in cache. How about first? I have an idea to create pre-cacheed storage. What do you think? But the data is dynamic, mean income addresses are different.

Comment: Anyway you have to make first request. If you want to pre-cache, you need to make a centralized cache on your server since `localStorage` and any other browser objects obviously are not shared between clients.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is here:
How to do geocoding on the front-end: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client
This leaves quote limit on the users end, avoiding server-side quota limits.

Instructions on usage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding